# Cannot find module: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, node-modules

I wanted to run my app and I suddenly got this error. Why?

this is what my order looks like in which i work.

```
./
├─ app.js
├─ .env
├─ .gitignore
├─ node modules/
│  └─ ...
├─ package.json
├─ package-lock.json
├─ models/
│  └─ advertiser/
│     └─ advertiser_info.js
├─ customer
└─ db/
   └─ advertiser_db.js
```

app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

/* ******** Database Connection ********* */
var db = require("./db/advertiser_db");


db.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
    console.log("Database connection successfull");
    app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
        console.log("Express listening on " + process.env.PORT);

    })
});
```

db/advertiser_db.js:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = new Sequelize(`${process.env.DB_NAME}`, `${process.env.DB_USERNAME}`, `${process.env.DB_PW}`, {
    host: `${process.env.DB_HOST}`,
    dialect: "postgres"
});

const db = {};

db.n_advertiser = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/models/advertiser/advertiser_info.js");
db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

models/advertiser/advertiser_info.js:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    return sequelize.define("advertiser", {
        blabla: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        blabla: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                isEmail: true
            }
        },
        hashedPw: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        blabla: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        blabla: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        blabla: {
            type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: true,

        }
    })
}
```

If i Run the app.js file i see this errors:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/yildirim/Desktop/nn_backend/db/models/advertiser/advertiser_info.js'
Require stack:
- /Users/yildirim/Desktop/nn_backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js
- /Users/yildirim/Desktop/nn_backend/node_modules/sequelize/index.js
- /Users/yildirim/Desktop/nn_backend/db/advertiser_db.js
- /Users/yildirim/Desktop/nn_backend/app.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Sequelize.import (/Users/yildirim/Desktop/nn_backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:481:62)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yildirim/Desktop/nn_backend/db/advertiser_db.js:10:40)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yildirim/Desktop/nn_backend/app.js:5:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/yildirim/Desktop/nn_backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js',
    '/Users/yildirim/Desktop/nn_backend/node_modules/sequelize/index.js',
    '/Users/yildirim/Desktop/nn_backend/db/advertiser_db.js',
    '/Users/yildirim/Desktop/nn_backend/app.js'
  ]
}
```

i saw that it shows me a path that doesn't exist at all. Why? I have never defined that path:
'/Users/yildirim/Desktop/nn_backend/db/models/advertiser/advertiser_info.js'

thanks for your helpful answers.

Comment: Did you install sequelize.js?

Comment: @RatnadeepBhattacharyya yes i do it

Comment: i think the issue here is module directory is not accessible from the location , try with higher privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening your file again from the original folder. I had the same issue now it's fixed, after changing the location.